# Abstract methods inheritance on Object

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract, arrayobject

I want to know if there is a way to do the following. I looked around but I couldn't find anything.

Say we have an abstract class `Animal`, and two other classes `pet` and `free` where `pet` extends `Animal`, and `free` extends `Animal`. I create a `table Animal[] a = new Animal[2];`
and I put object of both classes inside it like this:

```
a[0] = new free();
a[1] = new pet();
```

and except the abstract methods inside my classes I have let's say the method `take()` inside free class like this

```
class free extends Animal{
    //other abstract overwritten methods
    public void take(){.....}
}
```

whith the instance of i find which class objct is and then i wanna call the unOveriten uniq method from each class 
so let say i have a method which takes an Animal object and i want to call its unig methods not abstract overiten like this :

```
  private void Add_Classic(Animal c){
            if( c instanceof free)
            c.take();//here is my question how can i call this non abstract method?
else{
c.take1();
}
        }
```

take () and take1() are Not abstract methods how do i call them

Comment: Can you give more details? What does calling `take` from inside `free` have to do with the `Animal[]`?

Comment: Please add more details and explanation to clarify your question. are you want say that `take()` is abstract method in `Animal` class and you override this method in subclass `free`? or it's only in subclass `free`

Comment: If this is an assignment, it's a bad one.  It seems like `pet` and `free` should be *properties* of `Animal`, not subclasses.